# css clip-path a jpg image

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I am trying to do the simpliest test of css clip-path, read the main websites about that and nothing works on my local.
I have been running in circle for some time and it is infuriating.
Even copying examples from the web won't at all provide any result.

I am just trying to... clip a simple jpg image with a circle.
I tried with a css defining clip-path and -webkit-clip-path, it does not work:  the img is displayed entirely without clipping.
I tried with svg clippath, it does not work:  the img is displayed entirely without clipping.

I use MacOs, I tried with the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox.  I use (test) Adobe Brackets to edit the html and css files.

I must do something wrong, I must.  But I cannot find what.  Can you please provide any help? Thanks!

Here is the example with just css:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Test Torche</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
<style>

.testClip {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(60 px at center);
    clip-path: circle(60 px at center);
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainPage">
    <img src="/img/Japan.jpg" class="testClip">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the example with SVG clipPath:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Test Torche</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
<style>

.testClip {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#testSvgClip);
    clip-path: url("testSvgClip);
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="testSvgClip">
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="25"></circle>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div id="mainPage">
    <img src="/img/Japan.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `svg` solution works fine if you add `testClip` class to the `img`. You can achieve your effect easily using `border-radius`

Comment: Now I feel stupid, thanks.  However, the idea is that the clip follows the mouse pointer.  So 1) I can't use border-radius 2) I believe it will be easier without svg section, so I can change the img style on mouse move.  But why the first option does not work?  I do everything by the book?

Comment: I meant thanks for the help, not thanks to make me feel stupid )